# Retrieve all values from a column using PARSE.com in .NET Windows 8 store apps

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, parse-platform

I have a class in my PARSE database as "Categories" with column name "category". The "category" column contains some values say like "sports","fun" etc. Now i need to retrieve all the values from "category" column.So that I could show the values in a listbox in my windows 8 app.I checked the [PARSE.com .NET Guide](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#objects-retrieving) and used the follwing code

`ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("category");` .Now how to get all the values of the category class and populate it in listbox?Hope I explained my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Categories");
ParseObject categories = await query.GetAsync("categoriesID");
var categoryList = categories.Get<IList<string>>("category");
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy and I did like this '  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Categories");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> res = await query.FindAsync();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
           foreach (var i in res)
            {
                var s = i.Get<string>("category");               
                list.Add(s);
           }'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Categories");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> parseObjects = query.FindAsync();
```